# Sass loop inside a map for DRYer code

Tags: css, sass

How can I make the following code more DRY? 
I have setup bunch of variables below that are later referenced in a `$colors` map. Currently I have to edit the code in two places to add a new color to the system. And these variable number will grow in the future considerably.

https://codepen.io/umbriel/pen/LLvPPK
Here is the whole **current** code section

```
$red : #cc0000;
$blue : #1e8cea;
$green : #27a249;
$teal : #41bdbb;
$purple : #5c369e;
$-yellow : #ecd340;

@function color-palette($color) {  
  $map: (
     light: scale-color($color, $lightness: 88%),
     lighter: adjust-hue(scale-color($color, $lightness: 48%, $saturation: 32%), -8%),
     base: $color,
     darker: adjust-hue(scale-color($color, $lightness: -36%), 0%),
     dark: scale-color($color, $lightness: -72%, $saturation: 100%)
  );
  @return $map;
}

$colors: (
 red: color-palette($red),
 blue: color-palette($blue),
 green: color-palette($green),
 teal: color-palette($teal),
 purple: color-palette($purple),
 yellow: color-palette($yellow)
);

// retrieve color from map ie. `color(primary, base)`
@function color($color-name, $color-variant:null) {
  // color variant is optional
  @if ($color-variant != null) {
    // map inception

    @return map-get(map-get($colors, $color-name), $color-variant);
  } @else {
    @return map-get(map-get($colors, $color-name), base);
  }
}
```

I have tried looping the map inside the `$colors` map which didn't work.

```
$colorvars : (    
  red : #cc0000,
  blue : #1e8cea,
  green : #27a249,
  teal : #41bdbb,
  purple : #5c369e,
  yellow : #ecd340
)

$colors: (
  @each $key, $value in $colorsvars {
    $key : color-palette($value)
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

## DRY adding colors (and its variations):

There's an excellent [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/managing-color-values-with-sass/) that describe how to do it better than I could ever explain. Basically you create a list of colors, then list of variations that contains what function should be applied to modify color and parameters for that function. Finally you kind of create an interface/one simple to use function for getting final color value. The important thing is that all colors and possible variations are declared in one place.

## DRY generating selectors:

Another thing you might consider is the way to generate all these selectors. You could use [@each](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_each__each-directive) directive to go through all colors and variations and generate all selectors/classes in 1 place. Something like:

```
@each $color in $colors {
  @each $variation in $variations {
    .c-#{$color}-#{$variation} {
      background-color: a-nice-function-to-get-color($color, $variation);
    }
  }
}
```

However, this usually isn't such a great idea, as it makes searching selectors in your IDE way harder. If you're really going to have so many different colors, then it might be worth thinking about using this technique, though.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I will read through the article you sent through. It looks quite extensive! And yes I will definitely generate the selectors at some point. Thanks for the snippet! Ill accept the answer if I find that article helped

Comment: HI Kamyl, looks like the article you sent through doesn't accommodate the usage of `color-scale` method which is essential for me. Its the only way I can avoid getting pure black and whites from a generated color.

Comment: I can see the problem. You'd like to do kind of this: `call(scale-color, #cc0000, $lightness: 88%)`. You don't want to provide `$red`, `$green`, `$blue` parameters that comes before $lightness in `scale-color()`. That's quite interesting case, I'm not sure how to solve this, sorry.

Comment: Actually you could make your own function that would wrap `scale-color`, but only receiving arguments you care about (skip $red, $green, $blue). Something like `@function scale-color-only-lightness($color, $lightness) {
  @return scale-color($color, $lightness: $lightness);
}`. This way you can just use it exactly like any other functions presented in article example. This is the simplest way I can think of (and the only one for now).

Comment: Another thing you could try is to also store in `$variations` parameters another list that would store parameter names as well. Then somehow build up your `$args...` to use inside `call()` using @each directive [multiple assignment](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Multiple_Assignment__each-multi-assign) and do something like `@each $parameter-name, $parameter-value in $parameters { $args.join($args, /* magic */) }`. If you choose to do it this way and succeed, please share it; I'd love to see it. :]